# Glowing lights travel from one end of face to other end?

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, faces

[image]

Assuming the shape is more complex, like a circuit board. How do I get glowing lights to travel on the faces and edges of the mesh from one end to the other?

Like in this video, from 0:00-0:02
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVT1lWwzz1o

1)
[image]

2)
[image]

3)
[image]

As per the screenshots, how do I get glowing effect to travel across the selected faces and edges of a mesh from one point to another?
Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the light simply goes from left to right (and doesn't follow the branches) so you could simply use a *Separate XYZ* plugged into a *ColorRamp* and play with the *Location* factors of the *Mapping* node to make the light move along the axis you want, plug the *ColorRamp* it into an *Emission*:

[image]

Comment: This works 100%. Thanks man. Appreciate it.